# iterating through a column in dataframe and creating a list with name of the column + str

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 coulmn, i want to iterate through the column headers, use that value and add a string to it and use it as the name of a list.

[rr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21LA3.png)

`resampled=pd.DataFrame()
resampled['RAT']=dd1['RAT']
resampled['SAT']=dd1['SAT']
rr=resampled-resampled.shift(1)`

```
for ind, column in enumerate(rr.columns):

name=column+'stuck'
name=[]    
print(name)
```

I want to get 2 list with names 
RATstuck
SATstuck

THank you!

Comment: Indentation after the `for` loop? line: `name=[]` you are reinitializing the variable name into an empty list. Make some efforts on the code.

Comment: You can't _name_ a list. Lucky for you there is [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried list comprehension?

```
[x+'stuck' for x in rr.columns]
```